# AngularJS: replacing text in a foreach loop

Tags: php, angularjs, http, service, foreach

New to Angular, I am accessing data from db via $http services and want to replace values in a textarea content matching words found in the db.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.translate = function() {
           $http
           .get('translate.php')
           .then(function(data){
                 var alldata = data.data;
                 angular.forEach(alldata, function(v,k) {
                      $scope.message = alldata.replace("\\b"+v.one+"\\b/gi",v.two);
                });
           }, function(data) {
                // error handling
         });
     };
 })
```

Textarea has `ng-model` of "message". It's not working and I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: alldata.replace is not a function
```

Comment: Can you confirm that alldata is a string?

Comment: @user2263572 ahh, alldata is an array. i changed it to $scope.message.replace but now i'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.translate = function() {
           $http
           .get('translate.php')
           .then(function(data){
                 var alldata = data.data;
                 angular.forEach(alldata, function(v,k) {
                      $scope.message = $scope.message.toString().replace("\\b"+v.one+"\\b/gi",v.two);
                });
           }, function(data) {
                // error handling
         });
     };
 })
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` error. Looks like it's not recognizing $scope.message?

Comment: you might want to make sure that your $scope.message is a string off the bat.  edited the answer.

Comment: if gives an error.  remove "toString()" all together.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Also FYI, the replace didn't work unless I used a regex object: `.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+v.one+"\\b","gi"), v.two)`

Comment: ah ok, interesting